# Re-utilizing Vector Stock Design

Tags: vector, images, copyright

I am wondering if I can re-utilize Vector Images that I bought from a stock image site without using the exact design.

For example, I have purchased several vector images that are called Set of 28 Brushes, which are pretty much splatters and strokes. I'd like to mix and match them on a different art board, add some text and print and sell the final design on t-shirts.

There are also other designs that are made of similar elements with brush designs and circular shapes, dots, etc. layered on top of each other that I'd like to re-utilize by just using select paths and moving them to another art board in the same fashion.Mixing and matching elements, while adding my own. Would this be a redesign that removes Copyright?

I did not purchase the extended licenses of the original vector images to print and sell so I am wondering if I take elements from the vectors I purchased and rearranged them on a different art board and added my own elements and text, would the design then be my own and would I be able to print the final design on t-shirts and sell them without worrying about Copyright infringement?

Comment: Your question is really a legal question. Legal questions (like what constitutes fair use) should be directed at a legal professional and not at the internet at large (like the GDSE).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the graphics you are talking about are “brushes.” I recommend you load those brushes into Photoshop (or another painting tool) and use them to paint your own original T-shirt design that is unquestionably both creatively and legally yours. You can rent Photoshop by the month if you don’t already have it.